# print an array of start date and end date in particular format in php

Tags: php, arrays

Following is a code snippet to divide a given start date and end date into weeks:

```
$start_date='2018-06-11';

$end_date='2018-06-29';
$output = array();
while($start_date<=$end_date){

$friday=date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('friday', strtotime($start_date)));

  $a['start']=$start_date;
  $a['end']=$friday;
 $output[] = $a;


$monday=date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('next monday', strtotime($start_date)));

  $start_date=$monday;
} 

print_r($output);
```

It produces the below result showing 3 weeks' start date and end date:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [start] => 2018-06-11 [end] => 2018-06-15 ) [1] => Array ( [start] => 2018-06-18 [end] => 2018-06-22 ) [2] => Array ( [start] => 2018-06-25 [end] => 2018-06-29 ) )
```

How to print in the following format:

```
Range: 11-Jun-2018 to 15-Jun-2018
       18-Jun-2018 to 22-Jun-2018
```

Comment: are you serious?

Comment: just use foreach like this `foreach($output as $arr) { echo date('d-M-Y',strtotime($arr['start'])).' to '.date('d-M-Y',strtotime($arr['end'])); }`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

use `capital M` for `Month name`

and add start date like this

```
$a['start']=date('d-M-Y',strtotime($start_date));

<?php
$start_date='2018-06-11';
$end_date='2018-06-29';
$output = array();
while($start_date<=$end_date){
    $friday=date ('d-M-Y', strtotime ('friday', strtotime($start_date)));
    $a['start']=date('d-M-Y',strtotime($start_date));
    $a['end']=$friday;
    $output[] = $a;
    $monday=date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('next monday', strtotime($start_date)));
    $start_date=$monday;
} 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem nice to answer. But still I pushed myself. Here is what you need to do:

```
$start_date = '2018-06-11';

$end_date = '2018-06-29';
echo  "Range: ";
while ($start_date <= $end_date) {

    $friday = date('d-M-Y', strtotime('friday', strtotime($start_date)));

    echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime($start_date)) . " To " . $friday . "<br>";

    $monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday', strtotime($start_date)));

    $start_date = $monday;
}
```